# What is the meaning of "be hidden so will need to" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "be hidden so will need to~" in the following sentences,

> On windows XP,windows 7 the hosts file is located in
>   c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\,
>
> Note: It may ***be hidden so will need to*** enable 'view hidden files'
>   to see it.
>
> In addition, you may not be able to save it unless you have opened it
>   as an administrator. Take look at this article for a guide.
>
> On Linux systems the hosts file is located in /etc directory.

(Source: Understanding and Using The Hosts File-Beginners Guide By steve )

Does "It may **be hidden so will need to** enable 'view hidden files' to see it" mean 
"It may **be hidden so that we will need to** enable 'view hidden files' to see it"?

If so, what grammar did these sentences (verb + so + verb pattern) apply to?
Is it possible to convert the verb + so + verb (be hidden so will need) pattern into a pattern with the subject and verb we are familiar with?

Is the verb + so + verb pattern without a subject grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is actually a typo. That clause needs a subject and it doesn't have one. Sometimes you might be able to get away with not directly stating the subject. This is not one of those times.

Presumably, there's a "you" (assuming this is instructions) right before the will. It could also be "we" as you guessed if he assumes you're following along and doing exactly the same things as him.